# What's the meaning of "CMD [ "-?" ]" in Docker?

Tags: docker

《The Docker Book v17.12.0-ce》 Page 223

> Listing 6.19: Our war fle fetcher
>   
>   FROM ubuntu:16.04
>   MAINTAINER James Turnbull 
>   ENV REFRESHED_AT 2016-06-01
>   RUN apt-get -yqq update
>   RUN apt-get -yqq install wget
>   VOLUME [ "/var/lib/tomcat7/webapps/" ]
>   WORKDIR /var/lib/tomcat7/webapps/
>   ENTRYPOINT [ "wget" ]
>   **CMD [ "-?" ]**
>
> This incredibly simple image does one thing: it wgets whatever fle from a URL
>   that is specifed when a container is run from it and stores the fle in the /var/lib
>   /tomcat7/webapps/ directory. This directory is also a volume and the working
>   directory for any containers. We’re going to share this volume with our Tomcat
>   server and run its contents.
>   Finally, the ENTRYPOINT and CMD instructions allow our container to run when no
>   URL is specifed; they do so by returning the wget help output when the container
>   is run without a URL.

Can anyboy tell me what's the meaning of "CMD [ "-?" ]"

I know the concept of ENTRYPOINT and CMD, 
what I don't understand is the meaning of "-?" in "wget -?"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figure it out, The author made a clerical error. The arguments in CMD should be "-h".
Because in the later he said " Finally, the ENTRYPOINT and CMD instructions allow our container to run when no URL is specifed; they do so by returning the wget help output when the container is run without a URL."

Answer (score 1):

When you run a Docker container, it constructs a command line by simply concatenating the "entrypoint" and "command".  Those come from different places in the `docker run` command line; but if you don't provide a `--entrypoint` option then the `ENTRYPOINT` in the Dockerfile is used, and if you don't provide any additional command-line arguments after the image name then the `CMD` is appended.

So, a couple of invocations:

```
# Does "wget -?"
docker run --rm thisimage

# Does "wget -O- http://stackoverflow.com": dumps the SO home page
docker run --rm thisimage -O- http://stackoverflow.com

# What you need to do to get an interactive shell
docker run --rm -it --entrypoint /bin/sh thisimage
```

Comment: I know the concept of ENTRYPOINT and CMD, what I don't understand is the meaning of "-?" in "wget -?"